# Excel downloaded using window.saveAs() is not opening

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, excel

I'm developing and application that has node.js at backend and Angular.js in front end. I'm using exceljs module in node to create a xlsx book. UI is making ajax call to download xlsx file.

Node.js code.

```
 response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + quoteId +".xlsx");

 workbook.xlsx.write(response).then(function () {
    response.end();
 });
```

Angular code

```
 DownloadService.downloadServiceCall(inputParam).then(
    function success(res){
       var blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: res.headers()['content-type'] });
       var header = res.headers()['content-disposition'];
       var fileName = header.match(/filename=(.+)/)[1];
       window.saveAs(blob,fileName);
    });
```

I'm able to download csv file and open it with above code.

Excel file is getting downloaded but I'm unable to open the same. It throws following error

[image: Error while opening excel downloaded]

Anyone have an idea about this issue, please suggest the solution. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It was due to async call from Angular. Has nothing to do with saveAs. Added responseType:'arraybuffer' in the request object. It resolved the issue.

```
$http({method:'get',url:'',responseType:'arraybuffer'})
```